# Return a multidimensional array from pointer function in C++-CLI

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I wrote following code to  return multidimensional array from pointer function.Input parameter of this function  is one dimensional array, output is pointer that point multidimensional array.

```
double  **function( array< double>^ data,int width,int height ) {
    int i;
    double **R = new double *[height];
    for (i=0;i<=height;i++)
        R[i]=new double [width];

    // ....

    return R;
}

int main( void ) {
    int M=2, N=10, i,j;
    // define multimensional array 2x10

    array< array< double >^ >^ input = gcnew array< array< double >^ >(M);

    for (j=0; j<input->Length; j++) {
        input[j]=gcnew array<double>(N);}
        double **result1 = new double *[N];
        for(i=0; i<=N; i++)
            result1[i]=new double [M];
        double **result2 = new double *[N];
        for(i=0; i<=N; i++)
            result2[i]=new double [M];

        //............

        // send first row array of multidimensional array to function

        result1=function(input[0],M,N);

        // send second row array of multidimensional array to function

        result2=function(input[1],M,N);

        for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
            delete R[k];
        delete R;}*/

    return 0;
 }
```

I built this program succesfully in Visual Studio 2008.When I debug this code,the program computed result1 pinter variable but during computing result2 in the function here:

```
R=new double *[height];
for (i=0; i<=height; i++)
    R[i]=new double [width];
```

Visual Studio give this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in stdeneme.exe
>   Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

Unfortunately I don't know  what to do.

Answer (score 9):

At a glance I see one error

```
for (i=0;i<=height;i++)
 {
 R[i]=new double [width];
 }
```

you have allocated R[height]
but the loop goes height+1

you should write the loop

```
for (i=0; i<height; i++)
```

Another thing I see is that when you want destroy your matrix you write

```
delete R[k];
```

but it should be

```
delete [] R[k];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I corrected **<=height** problem and did it **< height** but the Visual Studio is going on give the same error.In fact,Visual C++ can compute result1.Unfortunately it can't do memory allocation for result2 variable.Do you have a comment about this topic?

Answer (score 3):

The `<=`s are your problem. Valid array indices go from `0` to `N-1`. Assigning to `result1[N]` is an access violation - that's the exception it's complaining about.